# Why tf.matmul running on cpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I encountered some problems while training my model, specifically, the training speed is sometimes fast and sometimes slow(fluctuating between 2-10 iters per second). After I used tensorboard to check the network operation, I found that the `tf.matmul()` node was running on CPU device. As follow:

[image]

This makes me quite confused, I try to use `tf.device('/gpu:0')` to enforce that node running on GPU, I also tried to lower the tensorflow version, but none of these work.
below is my code:

```
def _repeat(x, n_repeats):
        with tf.variable_scope('_repeat'):
            rep = tf.transpose(
                tf.expand_dims(tf.ones(shape=tf_v.stack([n_repeats, ])), 1), [1, 0])
            rep = tf.cast(rep, tf.int32)
#             with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            x = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(x, (-1, 1)), rep)
            return tf.reshape(x, [-1])
```

by the way, the tensorflow version is 2.2.5, GPU is rtx3090.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason could be that the GPU has not been configured in your system properly. This is why it's detecting the CPU only. Make sure you have `Tensorflow GPU` installed in your system along with other [GPU support](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) requirements.

If a TensorFlow operation has both CPU and GPU implementations, by default, the GPU device is prioritized when the operation is assigned.

I tried replicating `tf.matmul()` in `Google colab` by selecting "CPU mode" and it could not detect the GPU:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())

# Place tensors on the GPU
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
  print(c)
```

Output:

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

But if we try the same by selecting "GPU mode", the tensor operation detects the GPU.

Output:

```
Num GPUs Available:  1
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) link to get more details in this.